# How do i filter a value of key in an object based on matching value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that contains objects. How do i filter out the value of "title" based on whether the id is matching?

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Fiction",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1957,
        "title": "Non-Fiction",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Literature",
    },
}
```

For example, if the const id=**1958**, then the output: **Literature**

Output:

```
Literature
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
let data = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Fiction",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1957,
        "title": "Non-Fiction",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Literature",
    },
};

let getTitle = (obj, id)=>{
 return Object.values(obj).filter(x=>x.id===id)?.[0]?.title
};

console.log(getTitle(data,1958))
```

You can also use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter`.

Without optional chaining as per OPs comment:

```js
   let data = {
        "0": {
            "id": 1912,
            "title": "Fiction",
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1957,
            "title": "Non-Fiction",
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 1958,
            "title": "Literature",
        },
    };

    let getTitle = (obj, id)=>{
      let element = Object.values(obj).find(x=>x.id===id);
      return element ? element.title : "";
    };

    console.log(getTitle(data,1958))
```

Comment: What does this part mean? **?.[0]?.title**

Comment: @Aly optional chaining; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I see, thanks! But this optional chaining giving me babel error issues :( @Giorgi Moniava

Comment: @Aly I updated the answer but I suggest you try to solve it yourself (use approach without optional chaining) first before looking at it.